# Entity Framework and roles

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an problem. I have a **User** which can have many **Roles**, but the **Roles** are global, so I have set up a table structure as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateModified] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastLoginDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserRoles](
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.UserRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [RoleId] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Roles](
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Roles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

The **UserRoles** table has foriegn keys set up for both the **Roles** and **Users** table on the respective **Id** columns.

In my code, I have this:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    // Stripped for brevity

    public IList<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Role : IRole
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<UserRole> Users { get; set; }

    public Role()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

**EntityFramework** is fine with this class and with my mapping as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().HasKey(m => new { m.UserId, m.RoleId });
```

Everything for the mapping works.
Now what I would really like, is for the **User** class to have a list of **Roles** and not **UserRoles**.

So, I would like it to look like this:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    // Stripped for brevity

    public IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

I am sure you can see the problem here.
Can someone think of a solution where my table structure stays the same, but I can access the **Roles** instead of the **UserRoles**?

Sorry if my explanation is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after something like this...

In DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(x => x.roles)
                .WithMany(x => x.users)
                .Map(x =>
                {
                    x.MapLeftKey("userId");
                    x.MapRightKey("roleId");
                    x.ToTable("UserRole");
                });
}
```

Now you have.

```
class User
{
   ICollection<Role> roles {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
class Role
{
    ICollection<User> users {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I should not have to create another table here, there must be something I can do to get the model to have access to the Role rather than UserRole.

Comment: This answer only uses the three tables you have already. In fact with this you would only have Users and Roles in your dbContext, the UserRole table exists in the db only to provide the mapping between them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this is just adding the **Role** to the **UserRole** class like so:

```
public class UserRole
{
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

This will then give me access to the **Role**.

Comment: There is no need for the UserRole class at all.

Comment: Ok, now you have updated your answer I can see what you mean. If I want to add a user to a role though, wouldn't I need this UserRole class?

Comment: Nope, just add the user to the users collection on the Role class, or add the role to the roles collection on the User class, save the changes, and EF will add the row to the UserRole table and update the collections so they are both correct.

Answer (score 0):

What approach are you following.? code/model/database first.I think you don't need the class UserRole.having collection in both Role and User is enough and EntityFramework is smart enough to figure out that you have a many-to-many RelationShip so it will create the join table inside the database but will expose it in code like this :
User.Roles.Add(Role arole)  and Role.Users.Add(User auser).

Hope this help

Edit: OOOps. the same answer was answered before me ..i didn't see it.